# The set of $n \times n$ symmetric matrices is a vector space with dimension $\frac{n(n + 1)}{2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, symmetric-matrices

I am told that the set of $n \times n$ symmetric matrices,

$$S^{n} = \{ X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \vert X = X^T \},$$

is a vector space with dimension $\dfrac{n(n + 1)}{2}$.

Naively, I would initially think that it should be a vector space with dimension $n^2$. However, since the matrix is symmetric, I then wonder if there would be "duplicates", for lack of a better term, which would give us something like $\dfrac{n^2}{2}$. But I'm not sure how one gets $\dfrac{n(n + 1)}{2}$. Could someone please explain this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denote by $E_{ij}$ the $n \times n$ matrix with a $1$ in position $(i, j)$ and zeroes elsewhere. Then the set of matrices
$$\{ E_{ij} + E_{ji} : i, j \in \{1, \ldots, n\}, i < j \} \cup \{ E_{ii} : i \in \{1, \ldots, n \} \}$$
is a basis of the space of symmetric matrices. Its cardinality is
$$\binom{n}{2} + n = \frac{n(n-1)}{2} + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \,.$$

Comment: What is the reasoning for $\binom{n}{2}$, which seems to be the set $\{ E_{ij} + E_{ji} : i, j \in \{1, \ldots, n\}, i < j \}$?

Comment: @DomFomello Because $E_{ij}+E_{ji}$ is a symmetric function of $i,\,j$. [Be careful!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_counting_(fallacy))

Comment: @DomFomello Choosing two integers $i, j \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$ with $i < j$, is the same as choosing two distinct integers $i, j \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$ where the order doesn't matter.

Comment: @punctureddusk Ahh, yes, I see.

Answer (score 2):

Each of the $\binom{n}{2}$ choices of matrix entries above the leading diagonal provides an obvious basis element for this vector space, as does each of the leading diagonal's $n$ entries. But$$\binom{n}{2}+n=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}.$$Equivalently, the number of degrees of freedom is reduced by the symmetry constraints:$$n^2-\binom{n}{2}=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}.$$

Comment: What is the "above-the-leading-diagonal matrix"?

Comment: @DomFomello See edit.

Comment: https://www.mathdoubts.com/matrix/types/square/leading-diagonal/